# Will forcely killing Android sticky service will restart it again?

Tags: android, service

I'm forcely killing my Android Sticky service from "Running Services". But its not getting start again by the OS automatically as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

1 - How soon it is restarted again when forcily closed by user through Running Services?

2 - How soon it is restarted again when OS destroys the sticky service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from my experience the answer is NO the OS doesn't call the service again if its forcefully shut down by user via "Running Services". It only calls the service `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method when application is destroyed (swipe away).

But I found a quick solution, as we know when service is destroyed the `onDestroy()` method is called. So just initialize the service again like this:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        startService(new Intent(context, TimerService.class));
        Log.v("App", "Service Started Again");
    }
```